# Tree menu - 4 levels

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, menu, tree

I have for my website a 4 level menu structure:
sections (in sections tabel), categories (in categories tabel, with section_id pointing to sections) and then pages (in tabel pages I have parent_id because a page can be actually child of another page, and also each page belong to a section).

How can I build the menu? (I use PHP and MySQL) 
Now I use 4 nested queries. First I select all sections, then for each section I select all categories, and for all categories I select pages without a parent, and then for each page I select child pages.

Also I can use just one query (with RIGHT JOIN) to get an array with section_id, category_id, page_id, parent_id. But I don't know how to convert this array to an tree array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4916-PHP-Build-a-tree-to-represent-an-SQL-query.html) to convert your query to a tree array.

[An example of use.](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/24896.html)

It's as simple as :

```
$sql_query = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE field3='val1' AND field4=5 OR field5='val2';";

$query2tree = new dqml2tree($sql_query);
$sql_tree = $query2tree->make();

print_r($sql_tree);
```